# generic testcontain for testcontainers throwing 409 saying container is not running

Tags: testcontainers

Here is my code sniplet

```
override val container = GenericContainer("memsql/cluster-in-a-box:latest")
container.start()
container.underlyingUnsafeContainer.setWaitStrategy(Wait.forHealthcheck())
container.underlyingUnsafeContainer.start()
container.underlyingUnsafeContainer.execInContainer("ls", "-al", "/") //throw 409 here
container.stop()
```

I saw in the console that say the container has started.  Not sure why I am getting 409 then.

Console log:Container memsql/cluster-in-a-box:latest started in PT0.406374S

Comment: Please add some more information for readers to answer your question correctly. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add some error output.